# JsPlumb not working in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jsplumb

I wanted to learn JsPlumb by following the example as below:

http://jsfiddle.net/aT63t/161/

I try to include this in ASP.NET MVC 4. However, it throws me with the exception of

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined
```

in my jsPlumb 1.4 version.

My jQuery version updated to latest 2.0.3 and Jquery UI with 1.10.3

Anyone have this issue before? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery is loaded and linked to correctly? Check your browser console.

Comment: My mistake... the jQuery loading problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- make sure you've referenced jQuery in your page.
- make sure that you first reference jQuery and jsPlumb after **Order is important**
  should be like this: jQuery, jQuery UI, jsPlumb
- in chrome right click the page "View Page Source" and click all the .js references to check if they are loaded, also check that you have jQuery referenced just once